# Howland source for adjusting slew

Tags: slew-rate

I am using a Howland current source and sink in the above circuit for adjusting slew rate, however I am not getting desired results.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fomURT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What are these desired results? What are you getting instead? What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: The current sources are added so as to get programmable slew rates, dv/dt=I/C; In the top howland source I am getting current in ~1.5mA range whereas for the lower current source i am getting ~474-600uA. Could you explain such contrasting behavior. Also I desire to control Slew through the voltages at the input of Howland sources. Appreciate your advise.

Comment: You can’t get a perfect design without specs because a perfect design is one that meets all specs.

Comment: @Hearth Specs: Achieve slew with minimum rise/fall time being 1ns and maximum being 25ns at output. I am able to achieve minimum rise time of 7.19ns with V2 set to 20V, R3 and R4 1kohm; V3:5V, R7 and R8 2.5kohm. Note i have used opamp LM741. On using ideal current sources i am able to achieve the requried specs. Could you comment on the howland sources?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Specs: Achieve slew with minimum rise/fall time being 1ns and maximum being 25ns at output. I am able to achieve minimum rise time of 7.19ns with V2 set to 20V, R3 and R4 1kohm; V3:5V, R7 and R8 2.5kohm. Note i have used opamp LM741. On using ideal current sources i am able to achieve the requried specs.

Comment: @AAA Well, the first thing that comes to mind is: Throw out those 741s and get some actual good op amps, 741s are worthless for anything other than demonstrating op-amp nonideality.

Comment: @AAA We're not supposed to do product recommendations here, so why not [look around](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/687) and see what you can find with adequate specs.

Comment: @AAA 1ns rise time means 350 MHz BW which you won't get with any regular Op Amps unless you look real hard and use stripline impedance control. It is just isn't practical for a newbie.  Go for 35MHz with 10ns at a practical limit 10~90%.. Even Scope probes wont do this unless you remove the ground lead and probe tip.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would be getting about 1.7mA however the output voltage at the op-amps has to be within its capability, given the supply rails and V1.

The voltage at the bridge top in steady state is the input voltage + 0.7V. Add the drop across 8k and we have Vin + 0.7 + 13.6V = Vin + 14.2V at the top end of R9.

Then we need more voltage at the output to get that node to Vin + 14.2V, which I'll let you work out, but most likely your supply rails are not high enough. You can try calculating if reducing R9/R10 and the input voltage and/or increasing the supply rails would do the trick. Be sure to include the actual output swing of the op-amp, many types cannot swing to closer than a volt or two of the supply rails while sinking or sourcing some mA of current.

Comment: Specs: Achieve slew with minimum rise/fall time being 1ns and maximum being 25ns at output. I am able to achieve minimum rise time of 7.19ns with V2 set to 20V, R3 and R4 1kohm; V3:5V, R7 and R8 2.5kohm. Note i have used opamp LM741. On using ideal current sources i am able to achieve the requried specs. Could you comment on the howland sources?

Comment: 741 op-amps don't do anything of value in nanoseconds. Maybe you could use a series inductor to provide the constant current for some microseconds or tens of microseconds until the op-amp catches up, if your desired current setting doesn't change too quickly. But inductors are far from perfect and that may not be sufficient.